# Can I assign a deconstructed array assignment to a variable and deconstruct it?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there's a way to deconstruct an array assigning it a variable and then pass the value to another deconstructed variable on the same line. Kindly see what I intend doing below:

```
const { prop } = [a] = chips.filter(x => x.id == 1);
```

Normally, I would do this in two lines of code like below:

```
const [a] = chips.filter(x => x.id == 1);
const { prop } = a;
```

Can I do that on a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just put the `{ prop }` inside where the `a` is currently:

```
const [{ prop }] = chips.filter(x => x.id == 1);
```

```js
const chips = [
  { id: 1, prop: 'foo'},
  { id: 1, prop: 'bar'},
  { id: 1, prop: 'baz'}
];
const [{ prop }] = chips.filter(x => x.id === 1);
console.log(prop);
```

(note that you also might consider using strict equality comparison with `===` if possible)

But if you only want to use *the first* matching element from the array, it would be more appropriate to use `.find` instead of `.filter`, because `.find` returns the found element, while `filter` returns an array (which you aren't really using):

```js
const chips = [
  { id: 1, prop: 'foo'},
  { id: 1, prop: 'bar'},
  { id: 1, prop: 'baz'}
];
const { prop } = chips.find(x => x.id === 1);
console.log(prop);
```

Comment: Sure, but neither does IE support destructuring, which OP is using :P (as usual, always use Babel and polyfills to get obsolete browsers to understand newer code)

Comment: Nice one, I was simply trying to be fancy. `find` is the appropriate thing to use here. Thank you.